# How to segment binary blob(s) into rectangles

Tags: python, opencv

I have structured forms I'm processing and I want to identify zones that should logically be processed together by OCR.

I am able to get decent results when I have a clean tables with fully bounded boxes but I have issues with open tables with missing edges or plain tabulated data separated by lines.

I was hoping I could detect the edges (vertical and horizontal) and split the black blob into the largest rectangles possible within the blob.

As an image is worth a thousand words here is what I am starting with:

[image: start]

And the regions I want to identify (more to be shown but you get the idea):

[image: target]

I've looked at blob detection and segmentation but I haven't figured out exactly how to approach this yet. Thoughts?

Comment: Where is the example image?

Comment: if it a well structured document, have you tried, MSER text detection ? 
https://github.com/azmiozgen/text-detection atleast it determines the significant regions